# How can we fetch dynamically created textbox values to another another php file

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin, server-side

I'm working with XAMPP 1.7.7[PHP: 5.3.8], MYSQL Server version: 5.5.16, Web server Apache/2.2.21, phpMyAdmin Version information: 3.4.5.

I'm trying to generate an application like if user enters the count ("Number_of_Bidders_Participated" according to my application) then display multiple a form (dynamically) for entering multiple client records.
And after that fetch all records values using PHP, dynamically create columns in table and insert values in that.

For example: user type count("Number_of_Bidders_Participated") value=3 then display 3 forms For updating client information.
I have done that with the help of JavaScript.

**I'm using the below code for that:**

```
<!-- Basic code-->
        Number of Bidders Participated:     
            <input name="no_of_bidders_participated" id="no_of_bidders_participated" type="text" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> 
            <input type="button" onclick="increment_value()" value="Add Bidders info" />
            <div id="container">
            </div>                      
<script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function increment_value(chk) 
        {       
            var get = $("#no_of_bidders_participated").val();           
            if (counter > 0)
            {
              return;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;                  
                for(i=1; i<=get; i++)
                {               
                       $('#container').append('<br>Bidder '+ i +' Name: <input id="biddername'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Address: <input id="bidderadd'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Phone Number: <input id="bidderphone '+ i +'" type="text" value=""/><br><br> Bidder'+ i +' Email ID: <input id="bidderemail'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Cotted Amount: <input id="biddercotted_amount'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Tender Awarded: <select id="biddertender_awarded'+ i +'"><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select><br><br><br>');
                }                                           

            }
        }   
</script>
```

on picture 1 you can see the output of this process.
Here i'm assigning `id="biddername'+ i +'"` for fetching data to another php file..
But, using the below code i don't getting the proper result.

```
${"biddername" . $i} = $_POST['biddername'.$i];
```

**Its showing the error below:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: biddername1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tender_monitoring_system\add_participated_bidders_info_submit.php on line 15
```

please help me for getting the below output. and please help me for dynamically create columns in MySQL server also.

Complete code : Mail file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>.::Tender Monitoring System::.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="date/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function increment_value(chk) 
        {       
                var get = $("#no_of_bidders_participated").val();   

                if (counter > 0)
                {
                  return;
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;                  
                    for(i=1; i<=get; i++)
                    {               
                           $('#container').append('<br>Bidder '+ i +' Name: <input id="biddername'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Address: <input id="bidderadd'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Phone Number: <input id="bidderphone '+ i +'" type="text" value=""/><br><br> Bidder'+ i +' Email ID: <input id="bidderemail'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Cotted Amount: <input id="biddercotted_amount'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Tender Awarded: <select id="biddertender_awarded'+ i +'"><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select><br><br><br>');
                    }                                           

                }
        }   

        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://localhost/tender_monitoring_system/"><img align="right" width="100px" height="40px" src="home.gif" alt="Home" /></a>
        <a href="http://localhost/tender_monitoring_system/add_participated_bidders_information.php"><img align="right" width="100px" height="40px" src="back.gif" alt="Back" /></a>    
        <div id="heading"><br><h1>Tender Monitoring System</h1><h3>Tender Status</h3><br>  
        </div>
        <?php
         $txtSearch = $_POST['txtSearch'];
         require('db_connect.php'); 
        // The form has been submitted, query results
            if ($txtSearch!='none')
            {
                ?>
                <center><br><br>
                <form id="search_form" name="search_form" action="submit.php" method="post">
                    <?php           
                    $queryitem = "SELECT tender_status,tender_number FROM tender WHERE tender_number='$txtSearch'";
                    // Execute the query 
                    $result = mysql_query($queryitem);  
                    ?><b>
                    Tender Number :     
                    <select name="qtender_number" id="qtender_number" disabled="disabled">
                        <?php   
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {   
                        $getvalue_number=$row["tender_number"]; //$getvalue_status has old tender_number value ramesh
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['tender_number'] ?>"><?php echo $row['tender_number'] ?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>        
                    </select>   
                    <input type="hidden" name="getvalue_number" value="<?php echo $getvalue_number ?>"> <?php //for passing variable value to another file?>
                    <?php           
                    $queryitem = "SELECT tender_status FROM tender WHERE tender_number='$txtSearch'";
                    // Execute the query 
                    $result = mysql_query($queryitem);  
                    ?><b>                   
                    Tender Call:
                  <select name="call" id="call">
                   <option selected="selected" label="none" value="none">- - Select Tender Call - -</option>
                      <option value="1st Call">1st Call</option>
                      <option value="2nd Call">2nd Call</option>
                      <option value="3rd Call">3rd Call</option>
                      <option value="4th Call">4th Call</option>
                      <option value="5th Call">5th Call</option>
                      <option value="6th Call">6th Call</option>
                      <option value="7th Call">7th Call</option>
                      <option value="8th Call">8th Call</option>
                      <option value="9th Call">9th Call</option>
                      <option value="10th Call">10th Call</option>
                  </select><b><br><br>                
                  Tender Status:  
                  <select name="tender_status" id="tender_status">
                   <option selected="selected" label="none" value="none">- - Select Tender Status - -</option>
                      <option value="AA Received">AA Received</option>
                      <option value="NIT Awaited">NIT Awaited</option>
                      <option value="NIT Received">NIT Received</option>
                      <option value="Online Tender">Online Tender</option>
                      <option value="Locked Tender">Locked Tender</option>
                      <option value="Opened Tender">Opened Tender</option>
                      <option value="Online Technical Opened">Online Technical Opened</option>
                      <option value="Online Financial Opened">Online Financial Opened</option>
                      <option value="Sanctioned For Award">Sanctioned For Award</option>
                      <option value="Rejected Tender">Rejected Tender</option>
                      <option value="Recalled Tender">Recalled Tender</option>
                  </select>               
                    Number of Bidders Participated:     
                        <input name="no_of_bidders_participated" id="no_of_bidders_participated" type="text" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> 
                        <input type="button" onclick="increment_value()" value="Add Bidders info" />
                        <div id="container">
                        </div>

                    <br><br>        
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form> 
                    <?php               
            }           
        ?>          
    </body>
</html>
```

submit.php file

```
<?php
    //$qtender_number = $_POST['qtender_number'];

    $getvalue_number = $_POST['getvalue_number'];
    $tender_call = $_POST['call'];
    $getvalue_status = $_POST['tender_status']; 
    $no_of_bidders = $_POST['no_of_bidders_participated'];

    echo $getvalue_number; //working
    echo $tender_call;
    echo $getvalue_status;
    echo $no_of_bidders;
    for($i=1; $i<=$no_of_bidders; $i++)
    {
        ${"biddername" . $i} = $_POST['biddername'.$i]; //problem here..
        echo ${"biddername" . $i};
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: This is a notice, not an error. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: can you please provide some sample code here..

Comment: why are you using `biddername.$i` instead of `biddername[]`?

Comment: i'm helpless to post images here...otherwise..i can show u with images...actually that is only for generating forms or multiple textbox for entering multiple bidder details

Comment: you cannot post images in comments but you can edit your post to include some. (you could upload your images and provide links if your rep is too low)

Comment: @jcho260: looks like php

Comment: my requirement is to dynamically display multiple forms based on the bidders_count then fetch that values using php and dynamically store that values into MYSQL.. but, i think it will not be a good approach i'm following, i'm still confused. :(

Comment: dear NickSlash i don't have enough reputation also..:( i'm new in this.. can you please suggest me some good method to solve this problem...

Comment: without seeing more/all of your current code it will be difficult for me to see what your approach is at the moment.

Comment: okey i will provide you

Comment: yes..added now you can check ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "name" attribute in your input tag,

```
<input name="biddername'+ i +'" id="biddername'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic variable names in php isn't usually the best idea, using an array might be a better idea but that wont be the problem with your code.

The following is just a little suggestion, i think your `increment_value` function is only supposed to run once, but the `no_of_bidders_participated` can change after you've run it. As this value is passed back to php in the `$_POST` it should be locked to prevent it being changed before the form is submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function increment_value(chk) 
{       
  var bidder_count = $("#no_of_bidders_participated").val();           
  if (counter > 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    counter++;
    $("#no_of_bidders_participated").setAttribute("disabled", true); // stop changes
    for(i=1; i<=bidder_count; i++) {               
      $('#container').append('<br>Bidder '+ i +' Name: <input id="biddername'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Address: <input id="bidderadd'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Phone Number: <input id="bidderphone '+ i +'" type="text" value=""/><br><br> Bidder'+ i +' Email ID: <input id="bidderemail'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Cotted Amount: <input id="biddercotted_amount'+ i +'" type="text" value=""/> Bidder'+ i +' Tender Awarded: <select id="biddertender_awarded'+ i +'"><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select><br><br><br>');
    }
  }
}   
</script>
```

Could you dump the php $_POST variable so we can see what you'r getting sent back to the server?

`var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);` should do it.

Comment: Dear NickSlash thank you for your support i will try to change your suggestions in my code..actually i'm providing only one time to enter the count there..

Comment: DEar NickSlash  if i try to add this code application is not working $("no_of_bidders_participated").setAttribute("disabled", true); // stop changes